# How do exceptions fit into a loosely coupled design that abstracts volatile dependencies?

Tags: c#, exception, dependencies

Let's says instead of coupling to the implementation code, you write an abstraction and inject an instance of the abstraction instead. For example, you can access a database with a repository:

```
abstract class MusicRepository
{
    public abstract IEnumerable<MusicTrack> GetTopFor(DateTime date);
}

class SqlMusicRespository : MusicRepository
{
    public override IEnumerable<MusicTrack> GetTopFor(DateTime date)
    {
        // use some database objects here... maybe they throw an exception
    }
}

class MusicService
{
    private readonly MusicRepository repository;

    public MusicService(MusicRepository repository)
    {
        if (repository == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("repository");
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public IEnumerable<MusicTopTrack> GetTodaysTop()
    {
        // domain logic that uses the repository to figure out what tracks
        // are in a (new, up, down, or same) position from yesterday
    }
}
```

I'm not certain what exception types should be handled from the consuming code, or exactly how exception handling should be done. The actual exception types change along with the implementation so trying to handle any particular seems to be a form of coupling.

Should an "exception adapter" be part of defining an abstraction... where each implementation catches any exception then throws this adapter with the caught exception as the InnerException instead?

```
public override IEnumerable<MusicTrack> GetTopFor(DateTime date)
{
    try
    {
        // use some database objects here... maybe they throw an exception
    }
    catch(Exception exception)
    {
        throw new MusicException(innerException: exception);
    }
}
```

That seems to be the idea with the .NET types derived from the WebRequest abstraction. Are there alternatives? Does having a catch handler for a specific type in the consuming code really violate Liskov anyway?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that interfaces should define a set of exceptions that they will produce, and define what assumptions may or may not be made about the state of the interface implementer when any other exception escapes.  There are at least three possible patterns here

1. Require that an implementer catch and rebrand any exception which does not imply that the implementer itself has a problem, so that any time the implementer throws an exception other than the documented ones, one can assume that the implementer itself is corrupted, or

   Require that the implementer let exceptions which are thrown from interfaces objects that it consumes pass through unless they corrupt the implementer itself, in which case they should be caught and rebranded.

   Require that the implementer catch and rebrand every exception as either a type which indicates that the request couldn't be completed but the implementer is probably not corrupted, a type which indicates that the implementer is corrupted but the CPU is probably not on fire, or else a type which indicates the CPU is on fire.

Unfortunately, Microsoft's existing interfaces like `IEnumerator<T>` don't document any such convention, meaning there's no defined way that something like an enumerable collection can meaningfully indicate that a condition exists which prevents enumeration but does not imply the CPU is on fire (`InvalidOperationException` would be most likely to result in proper behavior from most `IEnumerable<T>` consumers, except that the documentation specifies that it means the collection was modified).